# Metro style: how to show filtering options for longlistbox in a proper way

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, xaml, microsoft-metro, appbar

I have a large collection of items with several parameters, so i'd like to give a user a possibility to have different filters: like order by time, by alphabet, or by categories.

How should i implement filter selection in Metro style? Should it be a menu items like this, but with "filter by alphabet" instead of "menuitem 1" ?

[image]

Edit:

Some more details: so, assume we have Movie items with 4 fields: name, year of release, genre and main actor's name. I'd like to allow user to set filtering by 1 of those 4 fields. Actually, it is not filtering or sorting, its more like categorizing.

Comment: It's difficult to give correct answer to your question, without knowledge about your collection, but in my opinion you need to use SettingsPage, where you can set filters(ListPicker in depth like a filter - it's good choice). And navigate to SettingsPage fro, one of menuitems.

Comment: @jimpanzer Well.. assume we have movie items with 4 fields: name, time of release, genre and main actor's name. I'd like to allow user to set filtering by 1 of those 4 fields. ListPicker sounds good, actually.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, i found [this](http://www.geekchamp.com/marketplace/components/phoneflipmenu) thing, looking quite nice.

[image]

Edit: though, be careful, it is not working the same as on the picture. At least, current version is not fading the screen, so other controls still would react on user input and Back button.

Answer (score 0):

No way - the `AppBar` menu is not the way to go. For filtered content, you would normally use `LongListSelector` (both on [WP7](http://www.geekchamp.com/articles/wp7-longlistselector-in-depth--part1-visual-structure-and-api) and [WP8](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/design/jj735577%28v=vs.105%29.aspx)). The filtering can be set by you when you group (or re-group) the items bound to the control - for the filter setter you could use any control (e.g. a auto-complete text input control or a `ListPicker`).

Comment: Yep, for rendering content i'm using LongListSelector. The question is how to show to user filter selection. For example, how can i move ListPicker to the separate control, and show it "on top" of LongListSelector?

Comment: Ah... looking like i can put ListPicker to CustomMessageBox. I guess, that is the way.

Comment: That depends on the way you are designing your application. CustomMessageBox, or you can just include it in a multi-row grid.